# Как сгруппировать по частичным данным в поле выражение SQL

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, group-by

К примеру у меня есть таблица `table`, в котором есть поле `detail`, вмещает примерно следующее

`CF=инфа информация;FG=данные группировки 1;DF=еще что-то;`

`CF=инфа информация;FG=данные группировки 2;DF=еще что-то;`

`CF=инфа информация;FG=данные группировки 1;DF=еще что-то;`

И мне нужно сгруппировать по `данные группировки 1, данные группировки 2, ...`

Как это сделать, и что можно почитать?

Comment: Идея такой группировки - плохая, следующий вопрос будет как оптимизировать запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В выражении `Group by` можно указывать как сами поля, так и их преобразованные с помощью функций значения. В обоих случаях только эти выражения можно использовать в самой выборке

Сама регулярка такая `FG=([^;]+)` ([пример](https://regex101.com/r/TxE85R/1)) при использовании необходимо указывать, что надо выбрать именно первую группу, т.е текст в скобках, c синтаксисом Oracle запрос будет выглядеть так

```
  select
    FG, <групповая функция по any_field> 
  from (select
          t.any_field, 
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.detail, 'FG=([^;]+)', 1, 1, '', 1) fg
        from table t)
  group by fg
```

Групповые функции работают на наборах строк с одинаковыми значениями в полях, которые определяется в `group by` и выдают один результат на такую группу. К групповым функций относятся `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX` и т.д.

Ключевые слова для поиска это *Групповые функции*, *GROUP BY*.

Небольшая вводная по регулярным выражениям есть в описании самой метки.

Пример статей [ссылка](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html), [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), [ссылка](https://regex.sorokin.engineer/ru/latest/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: Спасибо, за решение)

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо получить только часть строки `detail` между метками ';FG=' и ';DF=', то в T-SQL это выглядит так:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(detail, PATINDEX('%;FG=%', detail)+4, PATINDEX('%;DF=%', detail)-PATINDEX('%;FG=%', detail)-4)
FROM table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(detail, PATINDEX('%;FG=%', detail)+4, PATINDEX('%;DF=%', detail)-PATINDEX('%;FG=%', detail)-4)
```

Результатом выполнения запроса для приведённого примера будут две строки:

```
данные группировки 1
данные группировки 2
```

А почитать необходимо про строковые функции.